# I want to Show Complex JSON Data in Flutter But Getting Nothing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to show the JSON data from a URL to my Flutter application and haven't found any solution yet.

How to show this data in the `ListView` in Flutter?

Here is my complete Flutter project code:

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jsontest/Json.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cricket',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: new JsonParseDemo(),
    );
  }
}
```

**Match.dart** Where Json Data is in organized form

```
import 'dart: convert';

Match matchesFromJson(String str) => Match.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String matchesToJson(Match data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Match {
  Match({
    this.name,
    this.status,
  });


  String name;
  String status;

  factory Match.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Match(

    name: json["name"],
    status: json["status"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "status": status,
  };
}
```

**Service.dart**  Here is the base URL to get JSON data

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'Users.dart';
class Services {
  //
  static const String url = 'https://api.cricket.com.au/matches';

  static Future<List<Match>> getMatches() async{
  try{
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (200 == response.statusCode){
      final List<Match> match = matchesFromJson(response.body) as List<Match>;
          return match;
    }
    else{
      return List<Match>();
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    return List<Match>();
  }
  }
}
```

And here is the code of my main class where I want to show the data.

**JsonParser.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Services.dart';
import 'Users.dart';

class JsonParseDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  JsonParseDemo() : super();

  @override
  _JsonParseDemoState createState() => _JsonParseDemoState();
}

class _JsonParseDemoState extends State<JsonParseDemo> {
  //
  List<Match> _match;
  bool _loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    Services.getMatches().then((matches) {
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Matches'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: null == _match ? 0 : _match.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Match match = _match[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(match.name),
              subtitle: Text(match.status),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to get "Name and Status" of the match from this JSON?

Comment: I think you should use State Management provided by flutter for efficient and smooth flow of data some of them are providers, bloc, flutter_bloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code below :

**json_parse_demo_screen.dart**

```
class JsonParseDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  JsonParseDemo() : super();

  @override
  _JsonParseDemoState createState() => _JsonParseDemoState();
}

class _JsonParseDemoState extends State<JsonParseDemo> {
  //
  List<Match> _match;
  bool _loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    Services.getMatches().then((matches) {
      setState(() {
        _match = matches;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Matches'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: null == _match ? 0 : _match.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Match match = _match[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(match.name),
              subtitle: Text(match.status),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**match.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

String matchesToJson(Match data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Match {
  Match({
    this.name,
    this.status,
  });


  String name;
  String status;

  factory Match.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Match(
    name: json["name"],
    status: json["status"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "status": status,
  };
}
```

**service.dart**

Here, you will have to check the hierarchy of the response you get.

The hierarchy of response is:

```
- meta
- matchList
    - matches
```

Then you have to look for the result you expect (here matches)

```
class Services {
  //
  static const String url = 'https://api.cricket.com.au/matches';

  static Future<List<Match>> getMatches() async{
    try{
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final responseFormatted = json.decode(response.body);

      final matches = responseFormatted["matchList"]["matches"];
      if (200 == response.statusCode){
        final List<Match> match = matches.map<Match>((item) => Match.fromJson(item)).toList();
        return match;
      }
      else{
        return List<Match>();
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      return List<Match>();
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `match`

```
List<Match> _match;
```

You can do it like this

```
Services.getMatches().then((matches) {
      setState(() {
         _match=matches
       _loading = false;
     });
    });
```